# How to enable #TODO/XXX/FIXME highlight in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide, spyder

I'm using Spyder for Python coding. However, I cannot have the highlight of #TODO/#FIXME/#XXX to work in Spyder. I have already checked the box in preferences setting. See the attached picture.[image]

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `### TODO:`?

Comment: Thanks for you tips. After adding `:` to the end, all of those are now recognized for highlighting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `:` to your keyword, for example `# TODO:`

Answer (score 2):

with the new versions (4.*.*) of spyder it works fine without any additions just

```
#TODO
#FIXME
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so I dug real deep into the question, and here is the real answer:
as of Feb, 2020, the relevant code can be found at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/aa9fdaf7379577bdc7c2aa1e2bdc3feb82be953b/spyder/utils/syntaxhighlighters.py line 492 or so, e.g.

```
    OECOMMENT = re.compile(r'^(# ?--[-]+|##[#]+ )[ -]*[^- ]+')
```

so, for the Spyder outline explorer (OE) to recognize your comment, it should

```
1. Start from the head of the line
2. Begin with either "#---" or "### " (be careful of the mandatory space)
3. Then optional spaces or "-", 
4. Then some more charactors that is NOT "-".
```

Following are working examples (tested on Spyder 4.0.1)

```
### foo
#--- bar
############# foo
# ---    bar
### ----foobar
#------------ foofoo
```

Comment: Not really. If you try to open files with spyder-highlighted comments in, say, PyCharm, it will specifically complain about this.